# Why does this gae example use a class method?

Tags: python, app-engine-ndb, class-method

`query_book` In [this](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries#intro) example is defined as `@classmethod`, and date is an attribute.

What does `cls.date` mean?

If it refers to an instance attribute, then why is it in a `@classmethod`?

If it doesn't refer to an instance, then whose `date` is it referring to?

EDIT

`date` doesn't seem to be a class attribute, because the following code prints out two different dates for the two instances. If it was a class attribute it would print the same value.

```
g1 = Greeting()
g2 = Greeting()
g1.put()
g2.put()
self.response.out.write(g1.date)
self.response.out.write("<br>")
self.response.out.write(g2.date)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because accessing the attribute `date` at class level allows to access the definition of the `ndb.DateTimeProperty` attribute, while accessing at instance level allows to access the value assigned to the instance.

```
type(g1.date).__name__ == "datetime"
type(Greeting.date).__name__ == "DateTimeProperty"
```

Answer (score 0):

`cls.date` is not an instance attribute, but a class attribute.

You can also use `Greeting.date`. But, if the class name is changed to Goodbye, it should be changed to `Goodbye.date` while `cls` version does not.

Comment: I edited the question because it was too long for a comment: `date` seems to be an instance attribute because its value is different in different instances.

Comment: @stenci, `<Greeting-instance>.date` is instance attribute, while `Greeting.date`, `cls.date` (in the class method) is class atttribute.

Comment: There is only one class definition with one `date` attribute. If `g1.date` != `g2.date`, then what is `Greetings.date`?

Comment: @stenci, Please read [Descriptor HowTo Guide](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html).

Comment: I just read that page, and I'm still confused. What is the difference between `Greetings.date` and `Greetings().date` (considering that `g1.date` != `g2.date`)?